# links with unique hover image fade in/out

Tags: jquery, image, hyperlink, hover, fade

I'm trying to do a menu, that shows different images when hovering over each link.
So far I've managed to do this, but I also want the images to fade in and out.

This is what I've got so far:
var $preview = $("#groupImg");

```
$(".link").hover(
  function() {
    $preview.attr("src", $(this).data("thumbnail-src"));
    $('#groupImg').css('opacity','1')
  },
  function() {
    $('#groupImg').css('opacity','0')
  }
);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mcx2u/

Thanks :)

BR
Martin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(".link").on({
    mouseenter: function() {
        var self = this;
        $('#groupImg').fadeOut('fast', function() {
            $(this).prop('src', $(self).data("thumbnail-src")).fadeIn('fast');
        });
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        $('#groupImg').fadeOut('fast');
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/mcx2u/4/)

Comment: Good answer, just wondered why assign this to self? `var self = this;`

Comment: @JamieRead - Cause `this` inside the callback isn't the same element ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with CSS3:

```
#groupImg{ transition: opacity 1s ease} 
//plus all the mixins
```

or with jQuery:

```
$('#groupImg').animate({'opacity':'1'}, 1000);
```